DynamicReports : XLS Exporter Issue
Facing below issue:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet
at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.ExporterTransform.xls(ExporterTransform.java:772)
at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.ExporterTransform.transform(ExporterTransform.java:136)
at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.export(JasperReportBuilder.java:914)
at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toXls(JasperReportBuilder.java:825)
at com.kmbl.gbs.reporting.util.ReportGenerator.generatePlainExcel(ReportGenerator.java:93)
at com.kmbl.gbs.reporting.util.SampleMain.main(SampleMain.java:116)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
... 6 more

For the following code snippet:
JRDataSource dataSource = createDataSource();
JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
report.setDataSource(dataSource).toXls(DynamicReports.export.xlsExporter("AAAA.xls"));

I am able to generate the xlsx pdf but issue only with the xls.
Need the xls to be generated. All other formats are getting generated
